# how to mock postMessage function of worker thread in jest?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, unit-testing, jestjs

I am using jest in nextJs with Typescript project to mock a web Worker code.
//worker.ts

```
addEventListener( 'message',handleMessage);
export async function handleMessage ( event )  {
  postMessage(['somemessage','somedata']);
}
```

//worker.test.ts

```
let postMessage = jest.fn();
  it(' should call post message ', async () => {

    await handleMessage('someeventdata');
    expect(postMessage).toBeCalled();

  });
```

output

```
TypeError: 'postMessage' requires 2 arguments: 'message' and 'targetOrigin'
```

why this mock is not working. I am able to mock the postMessage from main thread on worker
e.g

```
someworker.postMessage = jest.fn(); // this test  works perfectly
```